# Function in Kotlin data class as argument leads to parceling error

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a data class in Kotlin hat is using the `@Parcelize` annotation for easy parcelization. Thing is I now want to pass a function to this class and I do not really know how to make the function not be considered during parceling.

This is my data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class GearCategoryViewModel(
        val title: String,
        val imageUrl: String,
        val categoryId: Int,
        val comingSoon: Boolean,
        @IgnoredOnParcel val onClick: (gearCategoryViewModel: GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit
) : DataBindingAdapter.LayoutViewModel(R.layout.gear_category_item), Parcelable
```

I tried using `@IgnoredOnParcel` and `@Transient` without success.

This is the compile error I get:

> Error:(20, 39) Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue' if you want it to be serialized using 'writeValue()'

And this `@RawValue` annotation does not work either.

Comment: **I now want to pass a function to this class** What do you need that and what are you trying to acheive

Comment: @Raghunandan I want this class to receive an implementation of a function so it can execute it through data-binding. But I also need this class to be parceleable, so its data can be sent to other activities, etc.

Comment: It'd probably be more useful to create another object with title, imageUrl, categoryId and comingSoon and then make this object Parcelable and pass this same object to your viewModel. `data class GearCategoryViewModel(val someObject: parcelableObject, val onClick: (gearCategoryViewModel: GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit)` That way you are not trying to serialise a `Function`.

Answer (score 10):

Just cast lambda to serializable, and then create object from

```
@Parcelize
data class GearCategoryViewModel(
        val title: String,
        val imageUrl: String,
        val categoryId: Int,
        val comingSoon: Boolean,
        @IgnoredOnParcel val onClick: Serializable
) : DataBindingAdapter.LayoutViewModel(R.layout.gear_category_item), Parcelable {

    fun onClicked() = onClick as (gearCategoryViewModel: GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit

    companion object {
        fun create(
                title: String,
                imageUrl: String,
                categoryId: Int,
                comingSoon: Boolean,
                onClick: (gearCategoryViewModel: GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit
        ): GearCategoryViewModel = GearCategoryViewModel(
                title,
                imageUrl,
                categoryId,
                comingSoon,
                onClick as Serializable
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Parcelize
data class GearCategoryViewModel(
        val title: String,
        val imageUrl: String,
        val categoryId: Int,
        val comingSoon: Boolean,
        val onClick: @RawValue (gearCategoryViewModel: GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit
) : DataBindingAdapter.LayoutViewModel(R.layout.gear_category_item), Parcelable
```

Use @RawValue with the onClick parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly a real answer but I would do it like this. Replace your function with class like this:

```
open class OnClick() : Parcelable {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromLambda(func: (GearCategoryViewModel) -> Unit) = object : OnClick() {
            override fun invoke(param: GearCategoryViewModel) = func(param)
        }

        @JvmField
        val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<OnClick> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) = OnClick(parcel)

            override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<OnClick>(size)
        }
    }

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this()

    open operator fun invoke(param: GearCategoryViewModel) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("This method needs to be implemented")
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) = Unit

    override fun describeContents() = 0
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val onClick = OnClick.fromLambda { vm -> /* do something*/ }
onClick(viewModel);
```

Comment: It wont work, as u do not write/read anything to/from parcel. But you can force it to work by saving lambda as Serializable into parcel.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of the question doesn't really make sense.

You can't deserialise this object if you don't serialise all of its properties.

You seem to want `onClick` to be `null` if this is deserialised, but even if that was possible, it'd throw a NPE because this property is not marked nullable.

Consider changing your architecture so you only serialise simple objects (POJOs or data classes) and not Functions.