# Kotlin - How to parcelize an object variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error :

> This is not support directly by 'Parcelize', Annotate the parameter type with @RawValue if you want it to be serialized using 'writeValue'

when I implemented @Parcelize

```
@Parcelize data class PersonUiModel (
    var personNo: String? = null,
    var personItemNo: String? = null,
    var packageId: String? = null,
    var userInfo: UserDetailUiModel? = null,
    var personInfo: PersonDetailUiModel? = null
) : Parcelable, Cloneable {

  override public fun clone(): PersonUiModel {
    return PersonUiModel(personNo= this.personNo, personItemNo = this.personItemNo,packageId = this.packageId, userInfo = this.userInfo, personInfo = this.personInfo)
  }
}
```

Thanks before..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383876/function-in-kotlin-data-class-as-argument-leads-to-parceling-error?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

Make `UserDetailUiModel` and `PersonDetailUiModel` `Parcelable` as well (using `@Parcelize` or not).

Or make them `Serializable` and use [`userInfo: @RawValue UserDetailUiModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606163/rawvalue-annotation-is-not-applicable-to-target-value-parameter) as suggested by the message, but this is a worse alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Add annotation @Parcelize and extends into Parcelable

```
@Parcelize
data class PersonUiModel (
    var personNo: String? = null,
    var personItemNo: String? = null,
    var packageId: String? = null,
    var userInfo: UserDetailUiModel? = null,
    var personInfo: PersonDetailUiModel? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Parcelable plugin for Kotlin from Preferences-> plugins
2. Extend your class from Parcelable
3. Right click on the name of your class and choose:  Generate -> Parcelable

It will generate all needed methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to Use @Parcable Annotation then you have to Set Your Kotlin version and Make Gradle as given below.
then you able to use @Parcable annotation...

Example

```
@Parcelize
data class Student(val id: String, val name: String, val grade: String) : Parcelable
```

-----Kotlin--------
    **Prerequisites:**
    Kotlin version 1.1.4 or newer

-------Gradle-----

```
builde.gradle


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

My Gradle File.....See as Example-------->

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```